How to position random and scale instances one after another with Instance on Points
I want to create a procedural tile with Geometry Nodes where the tile can have a maximum and minimum size. The tiles should not overlap each other.
At the moment I have the following result, only the first column works as it should, the tiles are located one above the other and have different sizes. In the rest of the columns, only the random size works correctly.

Node setup

Please tell me how I can set the offset of each tile in each subsequent column based on the size of each tile?

Do they all have the same width?

My suggestion is that you explore a "repeat zone" node, treat X outside and Y inside the repeat.
